# jQuery fadeOut() and clicking issue

Tags: jquery, click, wait, fadeout

This is for a returner, as part of a PHP-driven CMS.

We want the returner (if has class *admin*) to add the div *hide*, which is a little X button. The returner should automatically fadeOut() after 4 seconds, or to fadeOut() if the user clicks on the *hide* button.

Each of the //HERE codes work on their own, but together it will only run the delayed fadeOut() and **not** the clicked one!

Any help would be great. Thanks, Nick.

```
$(".success, .info, .warning, .error").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("admin")){
        $(this).append('<div class="hide"></div>');
        $(this).delay(4000).fadeOut(); // HERE
    }
});
$(".hide").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(); // HERE
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `.hide` is appended dynamically you need to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)) for the click handler to function correctly.

Since you are using a `delay()` try to call [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) on the parent to clear the delay to run the fade out animation.

```
$(".hide").live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().stop().fadeOut(); // HERE
});
```

Example of it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/8aDr8/).

Comment: Try replacing the `$(".hide").click` with the `$(".hide").live("click", function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).hasClass("admin")){}else{
```

This line can be cleaner by using an ! before the $

```
if ( !$(this).hasClass("admin") ) {
```

That avoids the unneeded if/else.  Can you post some HTML to see what parent() is referring to?

Comment: Thanks, wondered if that was the case!

`<div class='warning'><strong>Admin Message</strong> $a_m</div>`

Comment: If that is your HTML then you probably don't need .parent() because .hide would be the element you'd want to hide...unless it's wrapped in a div.  Try adding `console.log($(this).parent());` and see what it outputs in Firebug's console tab.

Comment: .hide is the actual X button, a div inside .warning